# Java server - processing of incoming sockets in multithreading mode

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

I have started writing the server in Java, based on sockets and I have some questions.
When I have the incoming request then ServerSocket returns Socket to me. Then I create the separate thread and use this new socket there. 
After some incoming requests, I have some separated threads and some sockets.
All sockets use the same input address and port.
Question -

How server understand to which thread he has to give input packet? Can
 you please give some advice about books or links that I can read to
 understand how the server works on low level?

How server (for example Apache tomcat) processing incoming sockets? 
As I understand, server has one input queue for input packet. 
 Is this queue affects on the server's speed?  Where can I read about such low level algorithm of server working?

Answer (score 0):

The `SocketServer` listens on a specific host and port. So called a listening socket. As soon as the server receives a new connection request, the server creates a new socket and binds it to the new connection.

[This link](http://microchipdeveloper.com/tcpip:use-sockets-to-establish-a-tcp-connection) explains the process a little bit deeper.

I will take a look if I find any other good reading material.

Answer (score 0):

Wernerson, thanks a lot! Good link!
As I understand I was wrong because I think that socket is only combination destination ip + destination port. But socket is combination destination ip, destination port, source ip and source port. And, as I understand, when client application create some sockets (new Socket(destination ip, destination port)), then all these sockets will have the same destination ip + destination port, and, maybe, the same source ip, but they will have different source ports. Yes?

Comment: A socket is a handle to a connection or an endpoint. That connection or endpoint has whatever properties it has. A listening socket is a handle for a different type of thing than a socket for a connection. TCP connections are identified by the source IP, source port, destination IP, and destination port. Your threads have handles that refer to TCP connections.